# C++ calling a Class Issue in Xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am Using Cocos2dX for one of my Game and i am new to C++. 
I am creating a Class 
The myDelegate.h 
    #include "cocos2d.h"

```
 class myOFDelegate : public cocos2d::CCLayer{
public:
    ~myOFDelegate();
    myOFDelegate();
   void RunME();
};

#endif
```

and myDelegate.m

```
include "myOFDelegate.h"

myOFDelegate::myOFDelegate(){    }

myOFDelegate::~myOFDelegate(){    }

void myOFDelegate::RunME(){
    CCLog("call me");
}
```

and i am calling RunME Method in my Hello Scene on a Menu Button Touch Like below

```
myOFDelegate *ofDelegate = new myOFDelegate();
    ofDelegate->RunME();
```

But i get This Errors Messages

---

```
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  
> "myOFDelegate::myOFDelegate()", referenced from:
>       HelloWorld::CallThis() in HelloWorldScene.o   "myOFDelegate::RunME()", referenced from:
>       HelloWorld::CallThis() in HelloWorldScene.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
> exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

Of-course when i Comment out the this Two lines

```
myOFDelegate *ofDelegate = new myOFDelegate();
        ofDelegate->RunME();
```

The Game Compiles and works Perfectly.

Can you help me guyz i have been pulling my hairs from 2 days and have not been able to figure this out

Regads
KK

Comment: you should start with posting correct code. Fisrt your method is declared as callingMe, you define it as RunME but then the error is about the constructor, so it's hard to figure out what exactly goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

If your code snippet above is an accurate reflection of what you have in your program, you have run into a difference between C++ and Objective-C. Unlike Objective-C, in C++ you have to declare all of the methods that your class will implement, even if you are overriding base class implementations. So, if you implement void myOFDelegate::RunME(), you need to have a declaration of that method in the associated header file. Where you have declared `void callingMe();`, below that declare `void RunMe();`.

You haven't shown us an implementation of the callingMe() method. Note that, as you have declared it in your header, you'll have to implement it too; You can't omit the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

are you using myOFDelegate.m or myOFDelegate.mm? in Xcode, cpp file and objective-c file are using different extentions.

and in your cpp file, using #include (not include or #import)

Answer (score 0):

What you have listed as being in myDelegate.m would not compile by default. The error you are getting is consistent with not building myDelegate.m in your project. Xcode determines which language the compiler should use by the extension:

- .m is Objective-C
- .cpp is C++
- .mm is Objective-C++

The code you listed for myDelegate.m is not valid Objective-C and requires some form of C++ compilation. You can change the language/compiler to use for particular files or change the default so for example *.m means Objective-C++. However, unless your project does one of these two things myDelegate.m won't compile as written. Are you sure it is really being included in the build? You can try slapping an `#error Test` line into `myOFDelegate::myOFDelegate()` to make sure really are building myOFDelegate into your project.

Answer (score 0):

You make .cpp class rather than .m class and then write the implementation of that class. if you do not want to make .cpp extension of that class you need to make .mm file on which you can write your c++ code.